# How to find documents in array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can i use mongoose.find() method to find the below code.

`Paid.find({info:{data:"status"}})`
This is not working as it is returning empty array

```
info{
  event: 'charge.success',
  data: {
    id: 1190118808,
    domain: 'test',
    status: 'success',
    reference: 'T458573232919212',
    amount: 100000,
    message: null,
    gateway_response: 'Successful',
    paid_at: '2021-06-26T00:25:33.000Z',
    created_at: '2021-06-26T00:25:24.000Z',
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MongoDB .findOne() function with nested document value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393025/using-mongodb-findone-function-with-nested-document-value)

Comment: try `Paid.find("info.data.status")`

Comment: I tried it but is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you use mongoose, it should be as easy as doing `YourModel.find({ data: { status: "success" } })`, this is assuming `info` is not an actual property on the document

Full Example (including data structure (the Schema), simplified):

```
const schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  data: {
    status: String
  }
});
const model1 = mongoose.model("model1", schema1);

(async () => {
  // connect the connection before this part
  await model1.create({ data: { status: "success" } });
  await model1.create({ data: { status: "failure" } });

  // this should only find & log the "success" one in the array
  const found = await model1.find({ data: { status: "success" } }).exec();
  console.log("found", found);
})()
```