# Model.updateOne() correct syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

using this schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  fName: String,
  lName: String,
  title: String,
  hash: String,
  salt: String,
  admin: Boolean,
  chats: [{ userid: String, messages: [{ user: String, message: String }] }],
});
```

what is the correct way to find a "_id" along with a specific "userid" using Model.updateOne()?

```
    User.updateOne(
      { _id: data.receiver, chats: { userid: data.sender } },
      { $push: { chats: mes } },
      (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(result);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
```

this ^^^^ doesnt work but this

```
    User.updateOne(
      { _id: data.receiver },
      { $push: { chats: mes } },
      (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(result);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
```

finds the correct user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MongoDB .findOne() function with nested document value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393025/using-mongodb-findone-function-with-nested-document-value)

Comment: The path for a field in an array is `"chats.userid"` _not_ `chats: { userid: ...` (which is used with objects). See [Specify a Query Condition on a Field in an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents)